# Get iterator to a element in sorted vector in log(n) time.

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a sorted vector and want to find a particular element in it. I can use `binary_search` for this but it only tells if it is present or not. I also need an iterator to access the element. Is there an easy way to this or I have to search it sequentially.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can't you have 3 iterators - one each for beginning, end, and mid?

Comment: Use std::lower_bound / std::upper_bound

Comment: @user1837009 You should make it answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get a "useful" C++ binary search algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446296/where-can-i-get-a-useful-c-binary-search-algorithm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound). `lower_bound` gives the iterator to the first matching element while `upper_bound` gives the iterator one past the last matching element.

If either algorithm fails to find a match, it returns an iterator to the place where the item could be inserted to maintain a sorted container.

I've always felt `binary_search` was misleadingly named.

Comment: Or `equal_range`, which gives you an easy test for present (`first!=second`) and if so gets you the element `*first`.

Comment: @mark romsom: Yes, and I always felt its wierd there is no "bool contains(start, stop, value)"

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` will return the first element that is **not** less than your value. Meaning  if the element returned is equal to your value your good, if it is ***not equal*** or the end iterator than the right element hasn't been found.

Here is the code from the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446296/where-can-i-get-a-useful-c-binary-search-algorithm)

```
template<class Iter, class T>
Iter binary_find(Iter begin, Iter end, T val)
{
    // Finds the lower bound in at most log(last - first) + 1 comparisons
    Iter i = std::lower_bound(begin, end, val);

    if (i != end && !(val < *i))
        return i; // found
    else
        return end; // not found
}
```

Remember if you use `std::upper_bound` than it returns the first ***greater*** element so it is not as easy to adapt to your purposes because if your element is indeed found you have to decrement the iterator and even then you still may not find it

Comment: And as I commented in the dupe: Don't use `*i == val`! Rather use `!(val < *i)`. The reason is that `lower_bound` uses `<`, not `==` (i.e. `T` is not even required to be equality-comparable). (See Scott Meyers' _Effective STL_ for an explanation of the difference between _equality_ and _equivalence_.)

Comment: @gx_ Thank you for the advice, I marked the question as a dupe and only posted the answer because the other answer was insufficient

Comment: Well, for completeness: after `i = std::lower_bound(begin, end, val)` there are only 2 possibilities (by specification): either (1) `i == end`, or (2) (`i != end` and) `!(*i < val)`. In case (2), we must still add the "swapped" test: if `!(*i < val) && !(val < *i)` (i.e. `!(*i < val || val < *i)`) then `*i` and `val` are equivalent (neither is less than the other).

Comment: @gx_ thank you for fixing the errors I wonder why the answer I took it from never bothered to fix it

Comment: No no no your last edit is wrong, the code `if (i != end && !(val < *i))` was correct! We must _first_ test if `i != end`, and if so _then_ `*i` is a valid expression and we _already know_ from the specification of `lower_bound` that `!(*i < val)` is true, so the only test that remains to be done explicitly is the "swapped" `!(val < *i)` (sorry if my second comment was confusing :s). (As for the source answer not "fixed": maybe because it's years old and I just commented :))