# C++ - Alternative to iterating vector

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, vector

I have a `std::vector<MyClass*>` (a vector of MyClass pointers), and I need to find a particular item in the vector. The class has a `getID()` function which returns a unique identifier of the class.

If I want to find a class with a specific ID, I iterate through the vector looking for the class with the ID, like this:

```
for(std::vector<Chunk*>::iterator it = chunksRenderList.begin(); it != chunksRenderList.end(); ++it)
{
    if((*it)->getID() == id)
        return *it;
}
```

This is rather slow because I am calling this code lots of times per second. I have tried using a `std::unordered_map` which was a lot slower, and a `std::map` was slower again. I'm not sure why it was slower, maybe it's the way I used it.

Is there any container/algorithm I can use to access a particular item without having to iterate (that is faster than iteration)?

Comment: Yes.  `std::unordered_map` and `std::map`.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` has amortized constant time for accessing an element. Iterating has O(N) complexity.

Comment: I have a hard time believing unordered_map was slower... You werent *iterating* on the map were you?

Comment: I would like to see the justification for the statement that maps are slower with some hard data. I simply do not believe it.

Comment: Yeah, I had a hard time believing it as well... Maybe I'm doing it wrong. This is how I was finding the item in the unordered_map: `try { return uomap.at(ID); } catch (out_of_range ooe) { return NULL; }`. Is that correct?

Comment: Seems reasonable. Where are the performance measurements?

Comment: @user2593738, Quick note: catch exceptions by reference.

Comment: @chris what exactly do you mean by this? When I profiled it, there was some exception handling taking up a lot of CPU time, maybe the exception handling is the problem. Please elaborate on your comment - it may be the solution.

Comment: Try `try { return uomap.at(ID); } catch (...) { return nullptr; }`

Comment: @Ed Heal tried that, no difference. I profiled it and RtlInitializeExceptionChain was using 50% of the CPU time!!!!!! What is it?

Comment: What is wrong with 50% CPU? Surely the time from start to finish is important and the OS gives you as much free CPU as possible. Better than being idle. So you need to learn about profiling.

Comment: CxxThrowException is also using quite a lot of CPU time... maybe I should try to reduce the amount of out_of_range exceptions thrown... are exceptions quite expensive? (there are HEAPS occuring in my case)

Comment: @user2593738: Yes, exceptions are generally *quite* expensive.

Comment: Don't rely on exceptions for searching.  Use `map::find` to check if the item is in your map.

Comment: @paddy - much faster. Must have been the exceptions! Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: @user2593738, You might give this a quick look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522299/c-catch-blocks-catch-exception-by-value-or-reference?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your container is sorted accoding to the value of getID() you may try using a binary search.

```
class A
{
  size_t m_id;
public:
  A (size_t id) : m_id(id) {}
  size_t getID (void) const { return m_id; }
};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct less_id
{
  bool operator () (T1 const &lhs, T2 const & cmp)
  {
    return (lhs->getID() < cmp);
  }
};

int main (void)
{
  std::vector<A*> v;
  v.push_back(new A(2));
  v.push_back(new A(3));
  v.push_back(new A(4));
  v.push_back(new A(5));

  less_id<A*, size_t> cmp;

  size_t find_value = 4;
  std::vector<A*>::iterator found = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), find_value, cmp);
  if(found == v.end() || !((*found)->getID() == find_value))
  {
    // not found
  }
  else
  {
    // found
    std::cout << "Found element: " << (found-v.begin()) << std::endl;
  }

  for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) delete v[i];
  v.clear();
}
```

Shows

> Found element: 2

Where `A` == `Chunk` and `v` == `chunksRenderList`.

Comment: Would that be the same as using unordered_map::find(id)?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be the same. The unordered_* containers use hashing to identify elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this enough to justify it, the obvious thing to do would be to sort the vector, then use a binary search to find your item.

If your ID's are reasonably predictably distributed over the range they cover, you could use an interpolating search to reduce the complexity from O(N) to roughly O(log log N) -- though it has enough higher constant that it's generally only a win with a fairly large collection.

Comment: By binary search do you mean should I check whether it is within the first half or second half, then check the first and second half of the half it's in and keep repeating this until I pinpoint the item?

Comment: @user2593738: Yes, exactly (though the standard library already has a "lower_bound" and "upper_bound" to do it for you).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446296/where-can-i-get-a-useful-c-binary-search-algorithm for an example implementation.

Comment: Or my answer where it's already adjusted for checking versus `getID()`.

Comment: Thanks @Pixelchemist I would +1 if I could (need 15 myself)