# Efficient Search through list of Ranges

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have list of ranges { start, end }, and a value (point) , now I am looking for effective way to get last n th index from range in which given value is present.

For example:
List: [ { 0, 4 }, {5, 10 }, {11, 14 }, {15, 20} , {21, 25} ]
n : 2
value: 22

So here, 22 is in range {21, 25 } which is at index 4 ( 0 based ). 
and since n is 2, function should return index of {11, 14 } because this is n th range from matching range.

Here, I can write binary function easily since I have sorted list of ranges. But I do not want to write while / for , I am looking for some C++ 11 / 14 algorithms / lambdas if available, which can solve this issue.

What is an efficient solution?

Comment: So if the value was e.g. `17` then you would return range `{5,10}` (i.e. index 1 in your "list")??

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I get a "useful" C++ binary search algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446296/where-can-i-get-a-useful-c-binary-search-algorithm)

Comment: is it accidental that those ranges are in order, non-overlapping, and leave no gaps? if not, that changes the approach, and should be stated in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like Jan's answer, but since the appropriate solution is notably different if your data *is* known to be sorted, here's an answer for the question as-asked:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template<typename RngT, typename ValT, typename OffsetT>
std::size_t find_prev_interval(RngT const& rng, ValT const& value, OffsetT const offset) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    auto const first = begin(rng), last = end(rng);
    auto const it = std::lower_bound(
        first, last, value,
        [](auto const& ivl, auto const& v) { return ivl.second < v; }
    );

    // optional if value is *known* to be present
    if (it == last || value < it->first) {
        throw std::runtime_error("no matching interval");
    }

    auto const i = std::distance(first, it);
    return offset <= i
      ? i - offset
      : throw std::runtime_error("offset exceeds index of value");
}
```

As the implementation only needs forward-iterators, this will work for any standard library container or C-array; however for `std::set<>` or something like `boost::containers::flat_set<>`, you'll want to alter the logic to call `rng.lower_bound()` rather than `std::lower_bound()`. Also, replace exceptions with something like [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/) if it is usual for `offset` to be too large to return a valid index.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your point is stored as a `std::pair` and that returning an iterator instead of an index is acceptable:

```
template <typename container_t, typename value_t, typename n_t>
auto KailasFind(const container_t& vec, value_t value, n_t n) {
    auto match = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const auto& p) {
        return value >= p.first && value <= p.second;
    });
    return match - n;
}
```

usage:

```
using point_t = std::pair<int, int>;
std::vector<point_t> vec {{0, 4}, {5, 10}, {11, 14}, {15, 20}, {21, 25}};
auto it_to_result = KailasFind(vec, 22, 2);
auto result = *it_to_result;
```

Comment: How is a linear search in a sorted list efficient?

Comment: @Henrik the author of the question did not specify that the container is guaranteed to be sorted. This answer aims to be as broadly applicable as possible.