# Find the biggest element in range that matches condition

Tags: c++, binary-search

Lets say I have range of integers [l, r) and a function `check(int idx)` which satisfies the following condition:
there is an index t (l <= t < r) such that for each i (l <= i <= t) `check(i) == true` and for each j (t < j < r) `check(j) == false`. Is there a standard way to find index t?
Standard `binary_search()` needs comparator that takes two arguments, so it can't be applied here (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: first of all, `std::binary_search` does not do what you need. It just checks whether a range contains the element - it does not return the index. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446296/where-can-i-get-a-useful-c-binary-search-algorithm

Comment: `t` is known, so even if `check` only takes one argument, you have 2 indexes to compare.

Comment: [`std::partition_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point)?

Comment: Along with using `std::distance` after getting the partition point.  That will find you the index.  So given your description, the solution is a one or two line function.

Comment: I’m not sure if std::partition works on a range of integers

Comment: Can we assume that the range is *already* partitioned or that's something the function needs to check too?

Comment: @Bob__ yes, we can assume that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are searching for a continuous range of integers (and not, for example, an indexed array) I would suggest a dichotomic search:

```cpp
int find_t(int l, int r) {
    // Preconditions
    assert(check(l) == true);
    //assert(check(r) == false); // this precondition is not mandatory

    int max_idx_true = l; // highest known integer which satisfies check(idx) == true
    int min_idx_false = r; // lowest known integer which satisfies check(idx) == false

    while (max_idx_true+1 < min_idx_false) {
        
        int mid_idx = (max_idx_true+min_idx_false)/2;

        if (check(mid_idx)) max_idx_true = mid_idx;
        else min_idx_false = mid_idx;
    }

    int t = max_idx_true;

    // Postconditions
    assert(check(t) == true);
    assert(t+1 == r || check(t+1) == false);

    return t;
}
```

This algorithm narrows the closest integers where check(idx) is true and the next one is false. In your case, you are looking for t which corresponds to `max_idx_true`.

It should be noted that the following preconditions must be satisfied for this to work:

- `l` < `r`
- `check(l)` is true
- for any `idx`, if `check(idx)` is true then `check(idx-1)` is always true
- for any `idx`, if `check(idx)` is false then `check(idx+1)` is always false

Below is a source code example for testing the algorithm and output lines to better understand how it works. You can also [try it out here](https://ideone.com/9LBSYI).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

// Replace this function by your own check
bool check(int idx) {
    return idx <= 42;
}

int find_t(int l, int r) {
    assert(check(l) == true);
    //assert(check(r) == false); // this precondition is not mandatory

    int max_idx_true = l; // highest known integer which satisfies check(idx) == true
    int min_idx_false = r; // lowest known integer which satisfies check(idx) == false
    int n = 0; // Number of iterations, not needed but helps analyzing the complexity

    while (max_idx_true+1 < min_idx_false) {
        ++n;
        
        int mid_idx = (max_idx_true+min_idx_false)/2;

        // Analyze the algorithm in detail
        cerr << "Iteration #" << n;
        cerr << " in range [" << max_idx_true << ", " << min_idx_false << ")";
        cerr << " the midpoint " << mid_idx << " is " << boolalpha << check(mid_idx) << noboolalpha;
        cerr << endl;
    
        if (check(mid_idx)) max_idx_true = mid_idx;
        else min_idx_false = mid_idx;
    }

    int t = max_idx_true;

    assert(check(t) == true);
    assert(t+1 == r || check(t+1) == false);

    return t;
}

int main() {
    // Initial constants
    int l = 0;
    int r = 100;

    int t = find_t(l, r);

    cout << "The answer is " << t << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The main advantage of the dichomotic search is that it finds your candidate with a complexity of only O(log2(N)).

For example if you initialize `int l = -2000000000` and `int r = 2000000000` (+/- 2 billions) you need to known the answer in about 4 billion numbers, yet the number of iterations will be [32 at worst](https://ideone.com/Fe3YDF).