# Using array of value_type for the stl::map

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, find, value-type

I have the following code:

```
//MyClass.h
class MyClass {
      typedef std::map<std::string, int> OpMap;
      static const OpMap::value_type opMap[OP_COUNT];

    public:
     //methods
};

//MyClass.cpp
const MyClass ::OpMap::value_type MyClass ::opMap[DDG::OP_COUNT] = {
    MyClass ::OpMap::value_type("hello", 42),
    MyClass ::OpMap::value_type("world", 88),
};
```

I need to implement function `bool findOP(string opKey)` which searches for `opKey` in the `opMap`.

Looks like I need to use a `find` method of the `map` class. But `opMap.find(opKey)` doesn't work, since `opMap` is an array of pairs. What is possible to do in order to search effectively for `opKey` in the `opMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your code and your question well... but if you want a `std::map` associating `std::string` keys to `int` values, why do you define an array of (key, value) pairs?

What about the following, instead?

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;
m["hello"] = 42;
m["world"] = 88;
```

I think if you have an *unordered* array (like `opMap` in *your* code), if you want to search something you can do a *linear search* (`O(N)`). Only if the array is *sorted* you can optimize the search using e.g. a *binary search* with `std::lower_bound()` (which has logarithmic asymptotic complexity).

If you want to initialize the map from the content of the `opMap` array, you can do something like this:

```
// opMap is an array of (key, value) pairs
// m is a std::map<std::string, int>
// 
// For each item in the array:
for (int i = 0; i < DDG::OP_COUNT; i++)
{
  // opMap[i].first is the key;
  // opMap[i].second is the value.
  // Add current key-value pair in the map.
  m[ opMap[i].first ] = opMap[i].second;
}
```

Comment: I used value_type for static "map initializatin",but I still want to use the map properties in orer to make effective serch (find)

Comment: @Yakov: I've added a sample code to initialize the map from the content of the array: just iterate through the array, and add each key-value pair in the map.

Comment: I don`t want to initialize the map from the array.I just thought that since the array is "built" from map ,it could be simple convension of array to map

Comment: @Yakov: If you want to use the "map properties" (as you wrote) you have to fill the map with some data. You have an array of key-value pairs, but it's just an array. You have to put this data in the map if you want to use `std::map` member functions.

Comment: @Yakov if you've got C++11 available to you, you can just initialize  a map directly. In C++03 you could use boost::assign, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2172053/1030301 for more info

Comment: Also, if you have to initialize at runtime, you could write that loop more succinctly as `std::copy(MyClass::opMap, MyClass::opMap + OP_COUNT, std::inserter(realMap));`

Comment: @je4d : Yes.I know that,but I still use C++10

Comment: @Yakov: there ain't such a thing as "C++10"... do you mean Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 whose C++ compiler is a.k.a. "VC10"?