# C++ alternatives to Java static blocks

Tags: java, c++, idioms, static-initialization

I am writing a date class where I want a static map to map "Jan" to 1 and so on. I am wondering how I can initialize that static map. This is what I am currently doing, but I just feel that the extra if statement is inelegant compared with static block in Java. I understand the compilation of C++ program is much more complicated, but I still wonder whether a better solution exists.

```
class date {
    static map<string, int> month_map;
    int month;
    int year;
public:
    class input_format_exception {};
    date(const string&);
    bool operator< (const date&) const;
    string tostring() const;
};

map<string, int> date::month_map = map<string,int>();

date::date(const string& s) {
    static bool first = true;
    if (first)  {
        first = false;
        month_map["Jan"] = 1;
        month_map["Feb"] = 2;
        month_map["Mar"] = 3;
        month_map["Apr"] = 4;
        month_map["May"] = 5;
        month_map["Jun"] = 6;
        month_map["Jul"] = 7;
        month_map["Aug"] = 8;
        month_map["Sep"] = 9;
        month_map["Oct"] = 10;
        month_map["Nov"] = 11;
        month_map["Dec"] = 12;
    }   
    // the rest code.
}

// the rest code.
```

Comment: There's a related question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c)

That might help you understand your options.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172053/c-can-i-statically-initialize-a-stdmap-at-compile-time also gives additional hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-c++11 systems: how about using a helper function and make `month_map` a *static const* member of `date` as it looks like you never wan't to change the association of the month's name with it's number, do you? This way `month_map` is initialized in your cpp-File and not in your constructor where it just messes things up. (Maybe you'll have several constructors in the future then you'll have to write a lot of boilerplate code)

```
const std::map<string, int> createMonthMap()
{
   std::map<string, int> result;

   // do init stuff

   return result;
}

const std::map<string, int> date::month_map(createMonthMap());
```

Answer (score 6):

In C++11 you can use initializer lists:

```
map<string, int> date::month_map = { {"Jan", 1},
                                     {"Feb", 2}
                                     // and so on
                                   };
```

In C++03 I believe you're stuck with what you are currently doing.

Comment: Actually, OP isn't stuck with what s/he is currently doing, seem my answer. Other than that sentence I want to upvote you...

Answer (score 0):

You can "implement" a static block feature in C++, even pre-C++11. See my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321324/1593077); it will let you do simply

```
#include "static_block.hpp"

static_block {
    month_map["Jan"] = 1;
    month_map["Feb"] = 2;
    month_map["Mar"] = 3;
    month_map["Apr"] = 4;
    month_map["May"] = 5;
    month_map["Jun"] = 6;
    month_map["Jul"] = 7;
    month_map["Aug"] = 8;
    month_map["Sep"] = 9;
    month_map["Oct"] = 10;
    month_map["Nov"] = 11;
    month_map["Dec"] = 12;
}
```

However, it is *much* better to use initializer lists, so if you have a C++11 compiler, do use those like @syam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408176/1593077) suggests.