# adding std::map to init list of ctor

Tags: list, dictionary, init

I want to add a std::map m_mapName in the initialization list of the constructor.

If I type m_mapName() in the constructor's init list, the compiler accepts it.

But, is it correct?
If it is not correct, how can I add the map to the initialization list?

Then, I do several insertions in the map. What is a more elegant way of inserting values, so I don't call insert function everytime?

---

More info:

Just like in : [C++, can I statically initialize a std::map at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172053/c-can-i-statically-initialize-a-stdmap-at-compile-time), the compiler doesn't accept syntax like:

```
std::map<int, char> example = { (1,'a'),
                            (2, 'b'),
                            (3, 'c') };
```

Cannot use Boost. 
My code looks like this:

*** className.h: ***

```
typedef std::map <uint16_t, int> mapType;

typedef std::pair <uint16_t, int> mapPair;

className{

private: 

    mapType m_mapName; 

}
```

*** className.cpp: ***

```
className::className () : 

m_mapName()

{

...

m_mapName.insert(mapPair(someMapValue1, 0));

m_mapName.insert(mapPair(someMapValue2, 0));

m_mapName.insert(mapPair(someMapValue3, 0));
```

Comment: Did you read the answers on the question you linked to that say exactly how to do this?

Comment: Yes, I did. The posting doesn't answer my specific question: Why did the compiler accept the way I added the map to the init list and if it is correct?

Comment: I also cannot use Boost.

Comment: That's not what your code looks like, you're missing `class` and a semicolon at least.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is correct.  And the linked question shows what to initialize it with

```
className::className () 
:m_mapName{ 
    {someMapValue1, 0}, 
    {someMapValue2, 0}, 
    {someMapValue3, 0}}
{}
```

Comment: The approach above gives me:
no matching function for call to 'std::map<short unsigned int, int, std::less<short unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const short unsigned int, int> > >::map(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

Comment: Changed the type from 'uint16_t' to 'int'. The code looks like: className::className () 
:m_mapName{ 
    {0, 0}}
{} Unfortunately, I get _expected '{' before 'm_mapName'_ and _expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '{' token_

Comment: I guess my code the way it is works because somehow m_mapName() calls some default constructor. But I am not sure

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce your issue: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cccca1a328c81c7