# Why do my map assignments cause a compiler error?

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors

I can't get my head around why this won't compile:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
m["jkl"] = "asdf";
```

I receive [this compiler error](http://codepad.org/aFyQS0br):

`Line 5: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.`

I swear I must be missing something simple here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m["jkl"] = "asdf"` is an expression. You can't have an expression on its own outside of a function body. The only thing allowed outside of function bodies are declarations and definitions.

Comment: `m["jkl"] = "asdf"` is an expression, `m["jkl"] = "asdf";` is a statement. Yes, since you ask, sometimes even I get bored of myself.

Comment: I had no idea that was the case. Guess I'd never tried it before. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if compilers could just tell that: "Statement found outside of function". It's a fairly common error, e.g. when you accidentily add a superfluous `}` to a function.

Answer (score 2):

That assignment needs to be within a function (i.e. *block scope*). If you want to initialize the map then you will have to do so at the point of definition. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c) is a related SO question (on initializing `map` at file-scope).