# Define a factory function that returns a pointer to a function created in this factory function

Tags: c++, c++11

My question is: **how to define a factory function that takes a parameter and returns a function pointer pointing to a function that is created according to that parameter? (or any other nice way to achieve the same result)**

---

**Explanation**

In essence, I want to define a factory function `set`, which takes a `std::string` parameter `str`, and returns a pointer to function `pf`. The function pointer `pf` points to a function, just created in `set`, that takes `std::ostream &` and returns `std::ostream &`.

In this way, I want to call with `std::cout << set(str) << "text" << std::endl;`. I hope that the result of `set(str)` lives at least as long as this statement.

For your reference, it is from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) that

> `ostream & operator<< (ostream & (*pf)(ostream &));`

---

**More Explanation**

This is for a real example, shown as below.

First I have manipulators

```cpp
std::ostream & black(std::ostream & os)
{
    return os << "\033[30m";            // make terminal text black
}

std::ostream & red(std::ostream & os)
{
    return os << "\033[31m";            // make terminal text red
}

std::ostream & green(std::ostream & os)
{
    return os << "\033[32m";            // make terminal text green
}
```

so that when I call

```cpp
std::cout << red << "this text is in red" << std::endl;
```

I will have the desired effect. So far so good.

Now with a map

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::string> code =
{
    {"black", "30"},
    {"red", "31"},
    {"green", "32"}
    // ...
    // could extend much longer as there are many colors
};
```

I hope to achieve a similar, customized effect with `foo("red")` with

```cpp
void foo(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << set(str) << ("this text is in " + str) << std::endl;
}
```

where `set` takes `"red"` and looks up the map `code` for the corresponding code `"31"`.

But I have problems in implementing the `set` function. I would appreciate it much if anyone could help me with this!

Two notes:

1. If possible, I want **good performance** for the `set` function, as it will be called again and again.
2. Forgive me please if I think the wrong way --- **So long as you can implement the functionality for `set`, I don't mind you do it in a different way.**

Thank you for reading this long post. Thank you very much!

Comment: `returns a function pointer pointing to a function that is created according to that parameter` It is not possible to create functions at runtime.

Comment: It absolutely is possible with lambda functions in C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why make things complicated?

```cpp
std::string_view color_from_name(std::string_view colorName)
{
    static const std::map<std::string_view, std::string_view> colors {
        {"red"sv, "\033[31m"sv},
        {"green"sv, "\033[32m"sv},
        {"black"sv, "\033[30m"sv},
    };
    return colors.at(colorName);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << color_from_name("red") << "tada" << color_from_name("green") << "got it\n";

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/nh2qMKoovh2qVlk2

Comment: This one has potential to be the solution. Will it work on case like `"bold_red_on_black"` where I want to parse the string and returns `"\033[1;31;40m"`? I plan to keep only 3 maps (instead of a very long one). One for style. One for text. One for background.

Comment: Answer to myself: I think so. Then yeah, why did I make it this complicated? I do not need to return a manipulator at all. I simply write a function that takes a string and returns a string.

Comment: I like this for simple modifiers. But I could imagine an API like `std::cout << color("red").bold().on("black")` with a class.

Comment: @JoshWilson That's a good suggestion. Might be off the topic. But what if people cannot remember the order and some may want to call `std::cout << color("red").on("black").bold()`? For design purpose, I do not hope to introduce too much coding burden.

Comment: Totally up to your design decision of course, but it's simple enough to make the order not matter. Just make a class with `on`, `bold` methods that set flags on the instance and `return *this`, then let the `operator<<` read the flags and produce the correct output.

Comment: @JoshWilson You're right. I should have realized this before making a comment all too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You **are** thinking the wrong way about it. What you need to do instead is to create you own parameterized manipulator. Such manipulator can be implemented as a separate class for which you have to overload `operator<<` :

```
struct set_color
{
    std::string name;
    explicit set_color(std::string name)
        : name(std::move(name)) { }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const set_color &color)
    {
        if (color.name == "black")
            os << "\033[30m";
        else if ... // and so on
            ...
    }
}
```

You can use a `map` instead to convert name to color code, but the basic idea is that there is no need to create a bunch of functions for this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I was on the wrong way. I think yours are the standard, strightforward way to solving my question. But it looks like Marek R's solution directly kills my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could globally define another overload of `operator<<` as such:

```cpp
using Manipulator = std::function<std::ostream&(std::ostream&)>;
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, Manipulator&>& func) {
    return func(stream);
}
```

```cpp
std::map<std::string, Manipulator> manipulators;
for (const auto& val : data) {
    manipulators.emplace(std::pair<std::string, Manipulator>(val.first, 
            [&](std::ostream& out) -> std::ostream& { return out << "\033[" << val.second << "m"; }
    ));
}
```

If you stored a map of strings to lambda functions as your manipulators, you should be able to make your `set()` function a simple wrapper returning your lambda.

Comment: Thank you @Josh Wilson. This could be one way. But considering on a terminal there are 7 styles (like `bold`) and 16 text / background colors, there could be around `7 * 16 * 16 = 1792` combinations of stylized colors. It looks like you want to load all these into a `map` that maps to `std::function`. Good part is everything would be ready at the beginning. Bad thing may be it will take a while. Consider this will be library, and you don't always need all these colors. This is my personal take.

Comment: Agreed, this would have a high setup cost. You could generate a new lambda function for each call to `set()`, and cache them for lookup next time. But @r3mux-n0x's answer is more idiomatic, and if you combined it with a [compile-type map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26079954/7619380) of your colors you could eliminate setup time.