# Map two different enums at compile time c++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I have two enum classes (C++17) and I want to map them but must be resolved at compile-time due to some performance issues.

Metaprogramming is a bit tricky for me yet.

enum NAMES {A, B, C}
enum LASTNAMES { A, B, C}

example:

```
Mapper::get<NAMES::A>::value // should return LASTNAMES::A
Mapper::get<NAMES::C>::value // should return LASTNAMES::C
```

we can use integers instead of the NAMES if it is not possible the case above.

1 ---> LASTNAMES::A

2 ---> LASTNAMES::B

....

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the question?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490835/how-to-build-a-compile-time-key-value-store