# Using a map as "Phonebook"

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have some code Similar to this

```
enum Days
{
MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
};

typedef void (*DailyFunction)(int);

namespace DailyFunctions
{
    void monday(int SomeData);
    void tuesday(int SomeData);
    void wednesday(int SomeData);
    void thursday(int SomeData);
    void friday(int SomeData);
    void saturday(int SomeData);
    void sunday(int SomeData);
}
```

and somewere else in my code I use a switch statement to assign one of the DailyFunctions to a DailyFunction ptr.
When i was typing the (more or less) same switch statement for the third time, I had the Idea, that it would be great to have a map

```
std::map<Days, DailyFunction> MyPhonebookMap
```

which would allow me to do something like this:

```
DailyFunction Function_ptr = MyPhonebookMap[WeekDay];
```

To me it seems, like the optimal place to define such a map would be in the namespace DailyFunctions under the function-declarations

But how can i define a const map there (since it shouldnt change) and populate it at the same time?

Comment: It's actually "Saturday" without an E.

Comment: I tried using a map as a phonebook once... got a lot of angry people answering the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boost function `boost::assign::map_list_of` or use a copy constructor to initialize `const map` from already constructed `map`:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<Days, DailyFunction> m;
    m[ MONDAY] = &monday;
    //... initialize m entries
    std::map<Days, DailyFunction> const mc( m);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. map_list_of was a great Tip :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is possible to use a simple array instead of the map. You can have an initializer for the const array, plus it will work faster.

```
    DailyFunction funcs[] = {monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, satureday, sunday};
```

Or, if you use C++11, you can use an initilizer list, like explained here [Initializing a static std::map<int, int> in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your fast answer. But that is not possbile, because I forgot one important information in my Post. And that is, that the enum doesn't start with 0 and goes to 6 but its more like monday is 7 tuesday is 28 and so on. This may sound very strange but i cannot avoid that. But I will try the Map initialiser u posted. I hope it works with VS 10 :)